# Git tree show untracked files

Tags: c++, git, libgit2

I am trying to fix this issue:
https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/issues/380

The problem is that the tree used in the model does not contain any untracked files and therefore the view has nothing to show. When I stage on file it is shown.

Is there a way to track in the tree also the untracked files?

I created a small test application to find the problem. When one file is staged, count is unequal to zero, otherwise it is always zero.

**Testsetup**

- new git repository (TestRepository) with the following untracked files:

  - testfile.txt
  - testfolder/testfile2.txt

d

```
#include <git2.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    git_libgit2_init();

    git_repository *repo = NULL;
    int error = git_repository_open(&repo, "/TestRepository");

    if (error < 0) {
      const git_error *e = git_error_last();
      printf("Error %d/%d: %s\n", error, e->klass, e->message);
      exit(error);
    }

    git_tree *tree = nullptr;
    git_index* idx = nullptr;
    git_repository_index(&idx, repo);

    git_oid id;
    if (git_index_write_tree(&id, idx)) {
        const git_error *e = git_error_last();
        printf("Error %d/%d: %s\n", error, e->klass, e->message);
        exit(error);
    }

    git_tree_lookup(&tree, repo, &id);

    int count = git_tree_entrycount(tree);
    printf("%d", count);


    git_repository_free(repo);

    printf("SUCCESS");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you're seeing is normal: as the file is untracked/new, the index has no knowledge of it, so if you ask the index, it has no "staged" changes to compare with, hence no diff.

If you want a diff for a yet-to-be tracked file, you'll have to provide it another way, usually by asking `git_diff` to do the work of comparing the worktree version with `/dev/null`, the empty blob, etc.

Since you're after a libgit2 solution, the way I'm trying to do that in GitX is via the `git_status_list_new` API, which gives a somewhat filesystem-independent way of generating both viewable diffs (staged & unstaged) on-the-fly, using `git_patch_from_blobs`/`git_patch_from_blobs_and_buffer`. In retrospect, maybe that should live in the library as `git_status_entry_generate_patch` or something…